# Error 500 after php upgrade to 7.2(Wordpress/Virtualmin)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, server, virtualmin

I let my host upgrade php version to 7.2 and after that I am getting error 500 message(Internal Server Error) on my wordpress page. 
I am using Virtualmin.

When opening error log I get the following:

```
 [Mon Jan 06 16:04:41 2020] [error] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/etc/httpd/bin/suexec' failed
[Mon Jan 06 16:04:41 2020] [error] Premature end of script headers: php7.2.cgi
```

I searched for the solution elsewhere but didn't find any solution. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: Contact your web host. There's an issue with `suexec` or something that's attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be something to ask your Hosting Provider, Potentially they have changed the PHP Handler (Eg from suPHP to FastCGI)

Comment: I'll contact with hosting provider. Will see what they say about this

Comment: You can also do a simple phpinfo check by creating info.php and putting `<?php phpinfo(); `  then browse to that page and look for `Server API` (Remember to delete this file after as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to >>> virtualmin >>> serve configuration >> website options

And make the change to
FCGI, fpm or what your system is available

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out the exact solution, but the web host told me that because this server had somehow been accessed by malware, this whole thing had to be closed down and the domain moved to a new address.

Moving domain to a new server solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have upgraded PHP, but your Virtualmin is not configured to use it correctly.

On Virtualmin go to system settings -> Re-check configuration, Virtualmin will detect new PHP version and configure it to use on your server.